# PostgreSQL: running SQL statements in parallel in a SQL script

Tags: postgresql, parallelism

I use a for loop in a script to compute geometries according to values in a series, and insert the results into a table (t1). Is there a way to rewrite the loop below using parallelism? What approach to use? I found many docs on how PostgreSQL runs queries in parallel, but hardy anything on how I could perform such task in my case. Is it even possible using SQL? or should I rely on other languages like Python, and execute the SQL queries from there?

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  lims int[];
  lim int;
BEGIN
  SELECT ARRAY(SELECT generate_series(60, 300, 60)) INTO lims;
  CREATE TABLE t1(
    lim integer,
    the_geom geometry(polygon, 4326),
  );
  FOREACH lim IN ARRAY lims
  LOOP
    WITH conv_hull AS (
      SELECT ST_ConcaveHull(...I use lim here...) AS conv_hull
    )
    INSERT INTO t1 (lim, the_geom) SELECT lim, ST_SetSRID(conv_hull.ST_ConcaveHull, 4326) FROM conv_hull;
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Comment: Why PL/pgSQL and a loop to begin with? This can be achieved with a single SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to run multiple statements in parallel in a single database session. For that, you'd have to run your loop in client code and execute SQL statements on different database connections.

But you may be able to rewrite that PL/pgSQL code as a single SQL statement. That will still run in a single database session, but it will be more efficient. If the query can benefit from that, PostgreSQL will automatically use parallel query to execute it with several processes.